# Unable to Access ArgoCD Web UI - Connection Issue

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, argocd

I'm having trouble accessing the ArgoCD web UI, and I'm seeking assistance to troubleshoot the issue. Here are the details:

**Problem Description:**

- I have successfully installed ArgoCD on my Kubernetes cluster using Minikube.
- The ArgoCD server appears to be running without errors, as confirmed by the following commands:
  kubectl get pods -n argocd

**Issue Faced:**

- When attempting to access the ArgoCD web UI via the browser at https://localhost:8080 (or via my VM IP addr), the connection fails.

**Additional Information:**

- I have tried restarting Minikube, but the issue persists.
- The port-forwarding command used is: kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443
- CURL result :

```
curl -k https://10.244.0.33:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.244.0.33 port 8080: Connection refused
```

**My endpoints and services**

```
[docker@localhost ~]$ kubectl --namespace argocd get endpoints
NAME                                      ENDPOINTS                                            AGE
argocd-applicationset-controller          10.244.0.27:8080,10.244.0.27:7000                    4m49s
argocd-dex-server                         10.244.0.32:5558,10.244.0.32:5557,10.244.0.32:5556   4m49s
argocd-metrics                            10.244.0.31:8082                                     4m49s
argocd-notifications-controller-metrics   10.244.0.28:9001                                     4m49s
argocd-redis                              10.244.0.29:6379                                     4m49s
argocd-repo-server                        10.244.0.30:8084,10.244.0.30:8081                    4m49s
argocd-server                             10.244.0.33:8080,10.244.0.33:8080                    4m49s
argocd-server-metrics                     10.244.0.33:8083 
                                    4m49s

[docker@localhost ~]$ kubectl --namespace argocd get service
NAME                                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
argocd-applicationset-controller          ClusterIP   10.97.235.204    <none>        7000/TCP,8080/TCP            5m20s
argocd-dex-server                         ClusterIP   10.109.215.13    <none>        5556/TCP,5557/TCP,5558/TCP   5m20s
argocd-metrics                            ClusterIP   10.106.29.80     <none>        8082/TCP                     5m20s
argocd-notifications-controller-metrics   ClusterIP   10.106.161.235   <none>        9001/TCP                     5m20s
argocd-redis                              ClusterIP   10.99.228.17     <none>        6379/TCP                     5m20s
argocd-repo-server                        ClusterIP   10.101.1.116     <none>        8081/TCP,8084/TCP            5m20s
argocd-server                             NodePort    10.101.40.35     <none>        80:32617/TCP,443:31182/TCP   5m20s
argocd-server-metrics                     ClusterIP   10.110.62.178    <none>        8083/TCP                     5m20s
```

I appreciate any guidance or insights to help me resolve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. I ran the following code:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443 --address 0.0.0.0
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443 --address 0.0.0.0
As mentioned above , Adding --address 0.0.0.0 to the above command made it work for me.

Comment: welcome, that was already answered in decemer 2023